# Output of Seurat FindAllMarkers parameters

Tags: r, seurat

I compared two manually defined clusters using `Seurat` package function `FindAllMarkers` and got the output:

[image]

Now, I am confused about three things:

1. What are `pct.1` and `pct.2`?
2. How come `p-adjusted values` equal to `1`? What does it mean?
3. If we take first row, what does `avg_logFC` value of `-1.35264` mean when we have cluster `0` in the `cluster` column? Is it that in cluster `0` the `Cttnbp2` gene downregulated by a factor of `2^1.35264`?

Comment: https://satijalab.org/seurat/de_vignette.html

Comment: You have a few questions (like this one) that could have been answered with some simple googling. I suggest you try that first before posting here.

Comment: I could not find it, that's why I posted. Thank you @heathobrien! Should I remove the Q?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `pct.1`– The percentage of cells where the gene is detected in the first group
2. `p_val_adj`– Adjusted p-value, based on bonferroni correction using all genes in the dataset.

> This is **not** also known as a false discovery rate (FDR) adjusted p-value.

An adjusted p-value of 1.00 means that after correcting for multiple testing, there is a 100% chance that the result (the logFC here) is due to chance.

3. You are correct. The expression of `Cttnbp2` donwn-regulated by that factor. If you were to look in the table at the cluster 1 DE genes you would see `Cttnbp2` with a logFC value of 1.35264. When you are looking at genes differentailly expressed in only two clusters, the sign is the only thing that changes.

[Vignette](https://satijalab.org/seurat/de_vignette.html) posted above by @heathobrien.

Comment: How the adjusted p-value is computed depends on on the method used (`use.test`). E.g. `"DESeq2"` uses Independent Hypothesis Weighting. While Bonferroni correction does indeed control the FDR as a side effect it is build to control the family-wise error error rate. An adjusted p-value of 1 does not mean that the result is due to chance, it just means that it cannot be excluded (by the methods used) that such a difference would be observed was there no true difference in expression.